# Consultas usando eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

estoy haciendo un ejercicio pero no se bien como estructurar la consulta. "Dado un ID de cliente 4781, escriba una consulta en MySQL para encontrar todos los pedidos de los clientes (id) y todos los productos relacionados con esos pedidos. El pedido debe ser devuelto incluso si no tiene productos."

y este es el codigo que estaba haciendo queriendo usar eloquent.
No se como hacer para traer todos los productos de ese (id).

```
$data = client::find(4781)->order->product;
return $data;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: quieres hacer una consulta donde si pasas el id de un cliente traer los datos de dicho cliente y todos los pedidos realizados por dicho cliente?

Comment: quiero que con el id del cliente me de todos sus pedidos y todos los productos del pedidos.

Comment: No, no los tengo hechos como solo me pedia escribir la consulta. Vos decis para hacer las relaciones no?

Comment: En el esquema te esta indicando las relaciones, lo mas lógico seria crearlas y a través de las relaciones crear la consulta de eloquent

Comment: Si no tenés creados los modelos de cada una de las tablas y sus relaciones, no vas a poder usar Eloquent. Crealos y actualizá tu pregunta con los problemas que te encuentres.